# croatian symbols

Tags: languages, localization

I wonder how I include croatian symbols into my Android device. I searched in the internet, but I can't find any useful information about this topic. Is it even possible to install "language packages" on a Android device, meaning that not the system language gets changed, but the range of possible symbols gets extended? (I'm running Android version 4.0.3 on a Samsung Galaxy SII)

Comment: In my `Settings | Language & input | Language` I see "Hrvatski" listed. Is it not available on your phone?

Comment: Yes of course, but this changes all to hrvatski. I only want to be able to input croatian symbols let's say in a SMS.

Comment: Ah. You may need to get an alternative keyboard, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a nice solution with

> Hacker's Keyboard

It's free available in the Google Store and you can choose between many keyboard languages. The nicest thing for me is that, even if I choose the croatian language, I can still easily write german umlauts, which I need as I live in Switzerland.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]